# Many error - what are they and how to solve?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I got many exceptions like:

```
Error   95  The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'MyProj.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   C:\Projects\Solution\MyProj\Web References\GeneralServices\Reference.cs 269 24  MyProj

Error   108 The type or namespace name 'Uri' does not exist in the namespace 'MyProj
.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)   C:\Projects\Solution\MyProj\Web References\GeneralServices\Reference.cs 322 43  MyProj
```

The only thing I sis was adding WCF service (I already have web services in the same project). How can I solve those errors??
Where did they came from??

For some reason I don't know people closed this questions because they think it is fake question. So this is not a fake question and if they need more information - they can be specific and ask and I'll provide it. I know it looks like very generic question - but I really don't know what info to add.

It is nor a refernces problem for sure. It happend after I add wcf service and the all errors accurs in Reference.cs file that generated after I added an external web service.

****EDIT****
Here is the code of the WCF service I added. I am not sure that it is the problem:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MyProj.Domain.Business.Entities.System.Calls;
using MyProj.Domain.Business.EntitiesRepository.System.Calls;
using StructureMap;

namespace MyProj.System.WcfServices
{
    public class SystemService : MyProjService, ISystemService
    {
        #region Calls

        public Reason[] GetCallReasons()
        {
            IReasonRepository rep =
                ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IReasonRepository>();
            return rep.GetReasonsList().ToArray();
        }

        public Call InsertCall(long reasonId, string phoneNumber, string description)
        {
            ICallRepository rep =
                ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICallRepository>();
            return rep.Insert(User.UserCompany.CompanyId, reasonId, phoneNumber, description);
        }

        public void UpdateCall(long callId, long reasonId, string phoneNumber, string description)
        {
            ICallRepository rep =
                ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICallRepository>();
            rep.Update(User.UserCompany.CompanyId, callId, reasonId, phoneNumber,
                description);
        }

        public void CloseCall(long callId)
        {
            ICallRepository rep =
                ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICallRepository>();
            rep.CloseCall(User.UserCompany.CompanyId, callId);
        }

        public IList<CallsListItem> GetCallsList(bool? isClosed)
        {
            ICallRepository rep =
                ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICallRepository>();
            return rep.GetCallsList(User.UserCompany.CompanyId, isClosed);
        }

        public Call GetCall(long callId)
        {
            ICallRepository rep =
                ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICallRepository>();
            return rep.GetCall(User.UserCompany.CompanyId, callId);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

****Another EDIT****
I remember that I also installed ef4.1 from [Here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=b41c728e-9b4f-4331-a1a8-537d16c6acdf&displaylang=en).
Maybe It make something??..

****Another Another EDIT****
I think I figure it out! but I still don't know how to fix this..
The file that creates the errors has `using System`, `using System.Web` and so on. The Im My project I have also System Folder and the WCF service is in `MyProj/System/WcfServices/SystemService.svc`. So, it creates a cs file with namespace `MyProj.System.WcfServices`.
This namespace confused with System namespace! Because the file that creates the errors is generated by the system (it is the References.cs file that created for web reference) I can't edit the file. How can I solve it?..

Comment: You say these are "exceptions," but they look like build errors. Do they happen when you compile the program or run it?

Comment: Can you add the code for the WCF that you added, include all of the frameworks you are referencing as well.

Comment: @Henry Jackson: You right - those are build errors. I treat them as exceptions.

Comment: @jon3laze: I added the code for the WCF, but I am not sure this is the problem.

Comment: How about narrowing down the problem? Comment out one of the methods and build. Do you still get the error? Yes, then comment out another and build? Still get the error? No? Then the problem was in that method.

Comment: open file C:\Projects\Solution\MyProj\Web References\GeneralServices\Reference.cs line number 269 and check what the class mentioned there is. have you renamed the class/namespace?

Comment: @John Saunders, @Sachin Nayak, @jon3laze: I figured out the problem thanks to you. Now I need to find out how to solve it.

Comment: "Not a real question" doesn't mean it's fake.  Your original got closed because you nobody could hope to answer with how little information you gave.  In this case think of it as "not a realistic question".

Comment: @Loren Pechtel: So closing the question solves it?? People who needs info can ask like @jon3laze did. Nobody has comment my former question but 6 people was closed it. This is not the right behaviour I expect as a decent user.

Comment: @Naor: you should read the [faq](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) and learn how the site works. It's not just about answering questions; it's about quality answers to good questions. That way, when someone a year from now has the same problem, they'll find the answer here. That would not happen with the question you originally asked.

Comment: @John Saunders: I can't understand how closing the question help you achive this goal? If you want someone to fix his mistakes - tell him to do so. Closing the question is like telling "Go away!" and I believe this is not what you tried to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution would be to stop naming folders "System"!

Another solution would be to qualify the system namespaces:

```
using global::System;
using global::System.Web.UI;
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks. Which name can I give to my System folder?

Comment: I don't know what you should name it, since I don't know what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

These mean that you're missing an assembly reference. E.g. you are referencing a type in your code for which you have not added a reference to your project. It sounds like you need to add a reference to System.Web by right clicking on your project and choosing "Add Reference".

If that doesn't work then make sure your project is targeting the full .NET framework instead of the "Client Profile" - do this by right clicking on your project and choosing "Properties" and then set the "Target Framework" on the "Application" tab.

Comment: This is absolutely not references problem. I have already System.Web and System.Uri and all the other refrences it requested. The project has already worked before. All the error are related to the Reference.cs file that generated in web reference to a web service.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it looks like the references are correctly added, perhaps there is a .NET version mismatch? .NET 4 Client doesn't support all WCF features, so that could be the problem. Sometimes intellisense and the complier don't quite see eye-to-eye, so it might look like everything is OK but then it fails to build.

You can check which version you're project is set to by right clicking on the project -> "Properties". Go to the "Application" tab, and check under "Target framework."